# What are you, laughing? vs. What, are you laughing?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Please watch [this clip of the movie Ant-Man, starting at 1:29](https://youtu.be/53GqgeSSUsU?t=89).

In the clip, the girl laughs at Ant-Man, who then retorts:

> What are you laughing?

Where should you put the comma, after *What* or *you*?

> a. What, are you laughing?
>
> b. What are you, laughing?

Is there any clear way of knowing which is correct?

And what's the meaning difference, if any?

Comment: It's "What, are you laughing?" and it may be more easily understood if you view it as some kind of a reduction of "What are you doing? Are you laughing?"

Comment: @Robusto Then, there's no such thing as (b)? Or is (b) used in some other context?

Comment: There is such a thing as (b) but not in the way you mean. People will say to someone who is acting immaturely: "What are you, ten?" (meaning ten years old). Or to someone who is ordering people around:  "What are you, king?"

Comment: @Robusto I know those expressions cold. I'm specifically asking whether (b) can ever be used.

Comment: You can use (b) if you like. It can be construed as (a) with the comma in a different place, after all—to me, the wrong place, but you seem pretty insistent, so rock on.

Comment: @Robusto I don't know what you're talking about. The only reason that I think (b) might be possible is because the speaker seems to pause after _you_, if you watch the video. And I'm not being "insistent". What's the point of being insistent and ask the question here?

Comment: There are no pauses in there, but there is a stress on *laughing*, which is consistent with  (a).

Comment: @Robusto Even if there's no pause, at least he says _What are you_ very fast as a single unit. No? I think in _What are you, stupid?_ there's a stress on _stupid_, too. Does that make it _What, are you stupid?_?

Answer (score -3):

It appears what the man is saying is:

*What... Are you laughing? C... Please, can you?!*

The separate sentences are not complete. I'd say the *what* was meant to begin something along the lines of *What's going on?* or *What are you looking at?*. The intonation of the sentence doesn't resemble the one in *What are you laughing at?*. Hence, the ellipsis.

OR

The *What* is only an expression of disbelief. Then, I'd transcribe it as:

*What? Are you laughing? C... Please, can you?!*

Then, he starts saying *Can you?*; stops; politely, adds *Please*; and continues with the elliptic *Can you?!* (meaning *Come on! Help me!*).

To answer your question - I think neither option you've presented is accurate (though the 1st one is the lesser evil). 
How to know which is correct? The knowledge of the rules of punctuation :)
The differences in meaning? Well, option a is, more or less, a transcription of what I have written above. As for option b, I would rather transcribe it as *What are you... Laughing???* As if Ant Man started asking *What are you doing/waiting for?* and then noticed the girl giggling, which was apparently highly upsetting for him. Hence *(Are you) laughing (at me, seeing me in such a pickle)???*

Comment: I don't notice any pause right after _What_. So I don't know what your "..." indicates.

Comment: @listeneva He's speaking fast. The ellipsis here doesn't imply he's making a long pause. It's for him not finishing the sentence. (Please note I gave you the 2nd option with the question mark.) It is definitely not "What are you laughing...?"

Comment: Why are you even talking about "What are you laughing...?", which isn't presented as a possible candidate?

Comment: Are you even familiar with "What are you, stupid?" If not, I have no further thing to say.

Comment: Let me put this way - neither of the options you've provided is punctuated correctly in my opinion. If I were to choose, I'd go with option A. Though I think it could use a correction. Does that answer your question? I don't know why are you're trying to be rude and opt for a storm-off as a means to discuss maters. I think "What are you, stupid?" might be a different sentence from a syntactic point of view.

Comment: Just so you know, the transcript of the movie is either (a) or (b). So it's not acceptable to claim that neither is correct, unless you provide some authoritative source to back it up, which you didn't.

Comment: I can see your point, but the place where the comma should be depends on where you can hear a pause. It is subjective, with the quick pace of speaking. True, I might have gone too far with the word "incorrect". What I meant was "inaccurate", as I said in the answer. Since punctuation in scripts tends to be simplified, I decided to rewrite it as "What...(or ?) Are you laughing?" for clarity. And that is all there is to it.